# MP3 ID3 Metadata no "Tags" tag?

Tags: tags, mp3, metadata, id3

In Windows 7, .WMA files have a property tag called "Tags" (e.g. song; music; pop;) with the use of semi-colons (i.e. ";") as the delimiter. Do .MP3 files have one? If not, it is such as pity.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What property exactly do you expect for "Tags"? The Genre of a Song like 'Pop'? What should the content "song" or "music" be?

Comment: Just added two pics. This is the tag "Tags". The name is "Tags", not Genre. .WMA have but .MP3 don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP3 files alone contain no metadata, but you can use ID3 tags within MP3 files to support metadata.

[ID3v1 contains these fields](http://id3.org/ID3v1):

- Song Title (30 characters)
- Artist (30 characters)
- Album (30 characters)
- Year (4 characters)
- Comment (30 characters)
- Genre (1 byte, giving 256 possible Genre IDs)

ID3v1.1 Added a track number field to this.

[ID3v2 adds many more fields](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0), one of which is a user-defined text frame.  This can be used for any data you want and could support a "user tags" field.

Why Windows 7 chooses not to use it, I don't know, but it doesn't matter really does it?  There isn't anything you can do.  What the client chooses to do with ID3 tags is up to it.

Comment: Does it mean that .MP3 have the "Tags" tag but Windows 7 ignores this field for some reasons?

Comment: @TinAmaranth MP3s don't have anything.  They can be enhanced with ID3 tags stored in the MP3 file.  There is no defined "tags" tag within ID3 tags, but there are user-defined parts that can handle such data.

Comment: Then, why is on Windows 7 that WMA files have got "Tags" but MP3 don't? Is it a in-built function in WMA or in ID3 tags?

Comment: Different media formats use different tagging structures.  One supports a "tags" field, others don't.